# Jenkins not recognizing my java in linux

Tags: java, linux, jenkins, opensuse

I am using OpenSuse and trying to install Jenkins using rpm. I have many trouble in this:

```
aquarius:/home/jeevan/Downloads # service jenkins start
Job for jenkins.service failed. See 'systemctl status jenkins.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

The problem is clearly stated in Jenkins [website](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Red+Hat+distributions) as a Java problem.

But I have already installed java in my machine by downloading from oracle website and configured the "update-alternatives"

```
aquarius:/usr/lib/jenkins # java -version
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
aquarius:/usr/lib/jenkins # javac -version
javac 1.8.0_25
aquarius:/usr/lib/jenkins # whereis java
java: /usr/bin/java /usr/lib64/java /etc/java /usr/share/java
aquarius:/usr/lib/jenkins # echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/java/latest
aquarius:/usr/lib/jenkins # update-alternatives --config java
There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                       Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib64/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk/bin/java   17147     auto mode
* 1            /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_25/bin/java              1         manual mode
  2            /usr/lib64/jvm/jre-1.5.0-gcj/bin/java       1500      manual mode
  3            /usr/lib64/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk/bin/java   17147     manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 1
aquarius:/usr/lib/jenkins # update-alternatives --config javac
There are 2 choices for the alternative javac (providing /usr/bin/javac).

  Selection    Path                                     Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib64/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj/bin/javac   1500      auto mode
* 1            /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_25/bin/javac           1         manual mode
  2            /usr/lib64/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj/bin/javac   1500      manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 1
aquarius:/usr/lib/jenkins # ls
jenkins.war                                                                                                                                                                                     
aquarius:/usr/lib/jenkins # whereis jenkins                                                                                                                                                     
jenkins: /usr/lib/jenkins                                                                                                                                                                       
aquarius:/usr/lib/jenkins #
```

Can some one please provide me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You're starting jenkins with java 8. This is a fairly new jdk which just recently got the status production-ready.

This bug in jenkins JIRA describes a similiar situation: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22270

The proposed solution there was to switch to java 7. Did you try that?

Comment: I have another system where it is setup with jdk 8 and it is working fine. There are two systems here where jdk 8 + jenkins are working fine.

Comment: If it is working in other systems with jdk 8, it need to work here with jdk 8 right? Some link is missing i think. How to find it?

Comment: Hmmm well theoretically according to jenkins docs it should work with any jdk >=1.6. So 1.8 should be fine.

Comment: I tried to create a link for /usr/bin/jar and now "service jenkins start" is working. But when in browser nothing appears. Now if I do "service jenkins status" it says "Unit jenkins.service entered failed state."

Comment: I've never use the ubuntu alternatives mechanisms as I've always had some problems with it. I always manually install java, simply by copying the unpacked tar with java in `/opt`, e.g. in `/opt/jdk1.7_51`, then making a symlink `/opt/jdk` to the java I want to use and then making symlinks in `/usr/local/bin`, e.g.
`sudo ln -s /opt/jdk/bin/java /usr/local/bin/java`
This way I have a pretty elastic mechanism of switching through java versions, installing new ones, etc. 
Maybe you could install java yourself and change jenkins to start with it?

Comment: That works in Ubuntu, but in OpenSuse you have pre installed Java Open JDK, which doesn't work for many cases. We need Oracle JDK. There will be several conflict between those two.

Comment: @JeevanRex sorry for not replying. Did you solve your issue? Did you perhaps try changing the java globally for Oracle JDK? Maybe you don't need to work with OpenJDK on some apps?